# Entity Relationship - Best way to handle relationship that expires after time

Tags: database, entity-framework, entity-relationship

Let's say there is a `Trip`, a `Bus` is assigned for each trip.

- So a `Trip` *has one* `Bus`.
- A `Bus` *has many* `Seats`.
- Each `Seat` has one `Booking` per `Trip`.

But each `Seat` *has many* `Booking` if you consider multiple days.

My question is what is the best way to implement this relationship between a `Seat` and `Booking` ?

For example:

I may store the `Booking` using a timestamp. So when I want to get current or next booking of a `Seat` I can filter using date. But the booking expires after the trip, so there will be a lot of expired data in the table.

Comment: What's the relation between bus and booking?

Comment: In my case the relation is between seat and booking, I dont book bus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Cobusve has the right idea: `Bus` and `Seat` are concrete objects; there's no reason you shouldn't give them a fairly permanent record in your database. `Trip` and assignment of `Passenger`s to `Seat`s for a given trip (which relation you've given the very appropriate name `Booking`) are all abstract, *transient*, concepts. (Actually, you should probably consider a `Passenger` table, and treat these records as mostly permanent, like `Bus` and `Seat`.)

`Bus` and `Seat` clearly have a 0or1-to-many relationship (i.e., each can exist independent of the other, `Seat` has a nullable foreign key BusId, and in EF, `Bus` has an `ICollection` of `Seat`, which might be empty) and can be set up anytime. Of `Trip` and `Booking`, clearly you're going to set up a trip before you make any bookings against it – you might even create trips well in advance, to provide potential passengers with upcoming schedules even before you start taking bookings.

Now, what is a `Booking` anyway? A booking is an association of a `Passenger` with a specific `Seat` for a given `Trip`:

```
class Booking
{
    public virtual Passenger Passenger { get; set; }
    public virtual Trip Trip { get; set; }
    public virtual Seat Seat { get; set; }
}
```

and add an `ICollection` of `Booking` to `Trip`. That's it. By convention, EF 6 will detect `Passenger`, `Trip`, and `Seat` as foreign relations on `Booking`, and will implicitly create foreign keys on the `Booking` table for them.

You can do some other things, either with `[Required]` or mappings to (1) ensure that the primary key of the booking is a composite key of these three foreign keys (2) cascade the deletes of all `Booking`s associated with a `Trip` with that `Trip`'s deletion, but this answers the original question you asked about how `Booking`s and `Seat`s should be related.

In particular, though, regarding a timer that auto-deletes a trip, you should be more intentional about it: chances are you want the details of trip to be captured somehow – say for billing or auditing – and don't want to have the trip just disappear from the database when the endtime of the trip passes.

Comment: Wow, thats some answer !! You identified some nook and corners. Thanks for the cool explanation. The Booking entity you provided is the way to go. +1 for "cascade the deletes of all Bookings associated with a Trip with that Trip's deletion". Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is a temporal relationship between the data. That gets really tricky really fast and is very hard to keep the constraints efficient and accurate to ensure data integrity.

It sounds in this case like a better solution for you is to not use the timestamp, but rather use the trip number as the differentiator.

That means you can get all the seats for a particular trip for a particular bus, or you can get all seats across all trips if you so desire.

Comment: Thanks for the "trip number as differentiator", its all making sense if I consider that, +1 on the way when I get to 15 reps I guess :) .

Answer (score 0):

You have trip and trip details (booking, bus).
I think your main table is trip so relationship should be between trip and booking also between trip and bus.
I think you don't need directly relationship between booking and seat.

when trip date expires that means other details (booking and bus) expires too.